# How to classify String Data into Integers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, classification

I need to classify the String Values of a feature of my dataset, so that I can further use it for other things, let's say predicting or plotting.

**How do I convert it?**

I found this solution, but here I've to manually type in the code for every unique value of the feature. For 2-3 unique values, it's alright, but I've got a feature with more than 50 unique values of countries, I can't write code for every country.

```
def sex_class(x):
    if x == 'male':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

*This changes the male values to 1 and female values to 0 in the feature - sex.*

Comment: Try: `df['country'] = df['country']..astype('category')`. You still see it as string when print, but underneath is stored as `int`.

Comment: Sklearn has all sorts of good built-ins for encoding categoricals into numerics. 
 OneHotEncoder, LabelBinarizer, LebelEncoder, OrdinalEncoder etc. found [in the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing)

Comment: Do you care what specific numeric value gets mapped to each country?  Or is any number okay, as long as they are unique and consistent?

Comment: For prediction, I think you would instead want `dummies`, not an integer for every group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rank` or `pd.factorize`

```
df['ID_int'] = df['id'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
df['ID_int2'] = pd.factorize(df['id'])[0]
```

#### Output:

```
  id  ID_int  ID_int2
0  a       2        0
1  b       3        1
2  c       4        2
3  a       2        0
4  b       3        1
5  c       4        2
6  A       1        3
7  b       3        1
```

The labels are different, but consistent.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the scikit-learn [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

`#given a list containing all possible labels
 sex_classes = ['male', 'female']
 from sklearn import preprocessing
 le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
 le.fit(sex_classes)`

This will assign labels to all the unique values in the given list. You can save this label encoder object as a pickle file for later use as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary instead.

```
sex_class = {'male': 1, 'female': 0}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the part of the problem OP mentioned in "but here I've to manually type in the code for every unique value of the feature"